# Android: Insert view below buttons with a Linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, button, view, touch

I'm trying to recognize button clicks is an app, which is being complicated by another view on screen. Basic setup:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trace_panel);

    drawCanvas = new TraceScene(this);
    addContentView(drawCanvas, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

When the button is clicked, drawCanvas is the view returned in onClick(). Im guessing because my insertion code places the view on top of the screen. I don't want to use a relative layout. Is there any way I can either insert drawCanvas into a specific z-index with a linearLayout? Or is there some other way to properly register the proper button when clicked?

Note: the buttons are at the top and bottom of the screen (I guess I could crop the view to fit between the toolbars, but I don't know how).